# Xamarin Studio, Missing Type or Namespace

Tags: c#, xamarin

I started using Xamarin Studio, and the version is 6.0.1 build 9.
I downloaded sample projects to check its behavior.
I downloaded the projects from the official website.

https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples

When I start building the project, the error happens as follows.

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `iOS' does not exist in the
>   namespace`Urho'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234)
>   (Urho.Samples.iOS)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FUiU.png)
I guess I need to fix the building setting, but I don't know how to deal with it.

I'd appreciate your advice.

Comment: Check under NuGet package node if all packages are restored. If not, restore them before compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing one or more NuGet packages as indicated by the message.

You can restore the package automatically by going to you solution view, find the project that is missing references, right-click the packages node and click the Restore option.

Here you can also Update all packages or add them.

[image: Packages context menu]

This is one of the first things you want to do when getting a external project of at first checkout. There is also the option of doing this automatically when building.

For this go the the Xamarin Studio menu option, the Preferences and find the NuGet section. Under General you can check an option to do this automatically when building a solution.

Also, you can let it check for updated packages. Then you will see the '(x.x.x available)' suffix like in the first screenshot.

[image: Xamarin Studio preferences]

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
Now I can build the apps perfectly!!

Comment: It works in many projects, but the same error happens even after restoring the packages in some cases.

Do you know any other ways to deal with this problem?

Comment: Please show what you see under the references node. Also please accept this as an answer if it solved your (original) problem. Thank you.